# How can one preview the source code of a library in CoDeSys 2.3

Tags: plc, codesys, structured-text

Is there any way to preview the source code of an imported library in CoDeSys 2.3? When I check the library *.lib file I can see it is not *compiled* nor obfuscated, but in the CoDeSys there is no option to get into it.

I've been browsing the web for the answer, but couldn't find anything meaningful.

Answer (score 1):

Technically it is possible to open a "*.lib" file in the Codesys 2.3 IDE if it is not encrypted, but I know that the IDE is customized according to the vendor. For example, I don't have "native Codesys 2.3" (directly provided by 3S Software) installed on my computer, but a version of SEW Eurodrive (PLC Editor), which contains some modifications dedicated to their PLCs. This version allows me to open *.lib files:

[image]

Maybe the version you have doesn't allow this.

**Here's a way to test it:**
If you create a project, add some function blocks and select "Save As" you will see that there are several options:

[image]

If you select one of the "Encrypted" options you will immediately be asked to enter a key, which will be prompted when opening the *.lib file.

Comment: Yes! I've managed to find it and it indeed does the work. Thank you for sharing a detailed instruction for the community!